# Content-length error in google cloud endpoints testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, google-cloud-endpoints

I get the following error whenever I want to test a 404 HTTP error path in my code:

> AssertionError: Content-Length is different from actual app_iter length (512!=60)

I have created a minimal sample that triggers this behavior:

```
import unittest
import endpoints
from protorpc import remote
from protorpc.message_types import VoidMessage
import webtest

@endpoints.api(name='test', version='v1')
class HelloWorld(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(VoidMessage, VoidMessage,
                      path='test_path', http_method='POST',
                      name='test_name')
    def test(self, request):
        raise endpoints.NotFoundException("Not found")

class AppTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app = endpoints.api_server([HelloWorld])
        self.testapp = webtest.TestApp(app)

    # Test the handler.
    def testHelloWorldHandler(self):
        response = self.testapp.post('/_ah/spi/HelloWorld.test', extra_environ={
            'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'Development/X', 'CONTENT_TYPE': 'application/json'})
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that the full error? I'm guessing not...

Comment: Me too -- it happens when you raise an endpoints exception on the server. I found this http://trac.turbogears.org/ticket/2454, but still have not fixed it -- I'll let you know when I do :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known error with App Engine.

Endpoints does not set the correct Content-Length header when you raise an exception:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10544

To fix it there is a `diff` file included in the link above, or follow my instructions to temporarily patch it by yourself.

**1. Open `apiserving.py`**

On a mac you can find the file at:

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0/endpoints
```

**2. Locate the following section (line 467):**

It should look like this:

```
headers_dict = dict([(k.lower(), v) for k, v in headers])
if self.__is_json_error(status, headers_dict):
  status, body = self.protorpc_to_endpoints_error(status, body)
```

**3. Change it to this:**

```
headers_dict = dict([(k.lower(), v) for k, v in headers])
if self.__is_json_error(status, headers_dict):
  pre_body_length = len(body)
  status, body = self.protorpc_to_endpoints_error(status, body)
  post_body_length = len(body)
  if pre_body_length != post_body_length:
    for index, header in enumerate(headers):
      header_key, _header_value = header
      if header_key == 'content-length':
        headers[index] = (header_key, str(post_body_length))
        break
```

**4. All done!**

Endpoints will return the correct Content-Length, WebOb will be happy and your API tests will be working :)